# Create Insert Statements by looping Datatable C#

Tags: c#, loops, datatable, nested

```
--------KEY----------------------------VALUE-----
newrowstart ------------------------newrowstart
LearnerTelephones_ID----------------3797d9ab-df28-423e-b847-f7c1abbac26a
LearnerTelephones_IsFirst-----------FALSE
newrowstart ------------------------newrowstart
LearnerTelephones_L_ID  ------------88a86894-f3fa-4ff0-bb0c-814a2434e841
newrowstart ------------------------newrowstart
LearnerTelephones_Ln_IDNAME---------my name
LearnerTelephones_Ln_IDAdd  --------my id address
newrowend   ------------------------newrowend
newrowstart-------------------------newrowstart
LearnerTelephones_Ln_IDNAME---------my name2
LearnerTelephones_Ln_IDAdd----------my id address2
newrowend   ------------------------newrowend
newrowend                   --------newrowend
LearnerTelephones_Notes     --------null
LearnerTelephones_TelephoneNumber---1234 505050
LearnerTelephones_UseForText--------null
newrowend---------------------------newrowend
```

My datatable is as above, and it has breaking rows- startrow and endrow.
I want to create insert statement out of this datatable, 
For ex.

```
insert into table1(LearnerTelephones_ID,LearnerTelephones_IsFirst,LearnerTelephones_L_ID , LearnerTelephones_Ln_IDNAME,
LearnerTelephones_Ln_IDAdd,LearnerTelephones_Notes,LearnerTelephones_TelephoneNumber,LearnerTelephones_UseForText)
values(,,,,,,..)
```

so total 4 insert statements i need to create.

Comment: loop through the rows of your tables, access the field values

Comment: if you are sure that you all data are correct, then you just create all insert statement into one string with Comma (;) delimeter. and pass all statement on one database call. So you dont need to write 4 different statements

Comment: @DynamicVariable i will pass all 4 insert statements in 1 call, but i need a way to construct these 4 statements as its "rowstart" within "rowstart".

Comment: its actually json which i m converting to Datatable:
 {"LearnerTelephones":{
        "ID": "eaf32af9-07bf-4d87-8aeb-84ac8860dee9",
        "IsFirstPointOfContact": true,
        "LocationType": {
          "ID": "ebbbaa62-f1f0-4010-8b0b-ee744eafc1de",
     "NameType":[{
    "IDNAME": "my name",
    "IDAdd": "my id address"
    },
    {
     "IDNAME": "my name2",
    "IDAdd": "my id address2"
    }
    ]
        },
        "Notes": null,
        "TelephoneNumber": "028 3282 3717",
        "UseForTextMessages": true
      }
}

Comment: please share json data.

Comment: First test your json : http://json.parser.online.fr/
I am not able to parse your json correctly.

Comment: changed @DynamicVariable

Comment: Thanks. that is working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104300/discussion-between-dynamicvariable-and-shradha).

Answer (score 0):

You should first write some classes which are useful to deserialize your json string.

```
class LearnerTelephones
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public bool IsFirstPointOfContact { get; set; }
    public LocationType LocationType { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool UseForTextMessages { get; set; }
}

class LocationType
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public IList<NameType> NameType { get; set; }
}
class NameType
{
    public string IDNAME { get; set; }
    public string IDAdd { get; set; }
}

class RootObject
{
    public LearnerTelephones LearnerTelephones { get; set; }

}
```

Then install newton.json package into your project, if not installed. 
[newton.json package link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

Then you can easily parse and deserialize json string into your  c# objects
and iterate as per your requirement, and can create insert statement.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {



        string json = "{\"LearnerTelephones\":{ \"ID\": \"eaf32af9-07bf-4d87-8aeb-84ac8860dee9\", \"IsFirstPointOfContact\": true, \"LocationType\": { \"ID\": \"ebbbaa62-f1f0-4010-8b0b-ee744eafc1de\", \"NameType\":[{ \"IDNAME\": \"my name\", \"IDAdd\": \"my id address\" }, { \"IDNAME\": \"my name2\", \"IDAdd\": \"my id address2\" } ] }, \"Notes\": null, \"TelephoneNumber\": \"028 3282 3717\", \"UseForTextMessages\": true } }";
        RootObject obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        string sql = string.Empty;

        if (obj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < obj.LearnerTelephones.LocationType.NameType.Count; i++)
            {

                var obj1 = obj.LearnerTelephones;
                sql += string.Format("insert into table1(LearnerTelephones_ID,LearnerTelephones_IsFirst,LearnerTelephones_L_ID , LearnerTelephones_Ln_IDNAME, LearnerTelephones_Ln_IDAdd,LearnerTelephones_Notes,LearnerTelephones_TelephoneNumber,LearnerTelephones_UseForText) values " +
                                          "('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}');", obj1.ID, obj1.IsFirstPointOfContact, obj1.LocationType.NameType[i].IDNAME, obj1.LocationType.NameType[i].IDAdd, obj1.Notes, obj1.TelephoneNumber, obj1.UseForTextMessages);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sql);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

I guess this will useful it. and update logic as per your requirement.

Comment: i want it to be generic, creating classes will not be possible where the scope of tables is 100+. That is why I m using parser to write it to Datatable first. also nesting levels are dynamic.

Comment: is insert statement's columns are fixed?